# Save State with Parallel cucumber tests

Tags: java, cucumber, guice, cucumber-jvm

We're using Cucumber/Guice to run UI tests in Java, and several step definition files spread out over the place.

My question is where is state maintained? If I wanted to run two separate tests with two separate runners, how the step defs classes treated? Is one created for each scenario? each feature? Or are they shared across instances?

For instance, would this ever be a problem? Would the following step-def be not thread safe?

```
public class StepDef  {

  private Properties props;
  private int num;

  @Inject
  public StepDef(Properties props) {
     this.props = props;
  }


  @Given("^the digit (\d)$")
  public void the_digit(int num) {
    this.num = num;
  }


  @When("^it is multiplied by 5$")
  public void it_is_multiplied_by_5() {
    this.num *= 5;
  }

  @Then("^the result is (\d)$")
  public void the_result_is(int result) {
    assertEqual(result, this.num);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is one instance of the class per runner. So what you are doing I think would be fine. For what its worth, we handled the parallelization problem in `cucumber-jvm` (and the storing of state across steps/features) using multi-threading in java (with variables local to each thread).  Its available on github - [zucchini](https://github.com/Comcast/zucchini).